# Invalidate and update the object from the cache with eclipselink

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

If i execute this query

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from  anomaly a where a.personId in ?1 and a.date in ?2 ")
void deleteByPersonIdAndDate(List<Long> personIds,
            Collection<LocalDate> days);
```

How the objects affected by this query are deleted from the eclipselink-cache ?

Comment: Why?  Is there a problem you are encountering?

Comment: I just want to know the mechanism of eclipselink-cache , to be sure that the data are updated correctly.If i change my question it would be , What's the class that are responsible of updating the data in the eclipselink 2.5 code source ?